# How to copy an table from one database to another database in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table **tbl_a** in schema **sch_a** in a database **db_a**
I want to copy this table **tbl_a** to schema **sch_b** in database **db_b**. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `pg_dump`. You will have to change the table schema after importing the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use copy :

```
sudo -u postgres psql --dbname=db_a -c "\copy (SELECT * FROM sch_a.tbl_a ) TO '/path/`date +%Y-%m-%d`_sch_a_tbl_a.csv' CSV DELIMITER '|' HEADER"
```

Then import it like so :

```
sudo -u postgres psql --dbname=db_b -c "\copy sch_b.tbl_b FROM '/path/`date +%Y-%m-%d`_sch_a_tbl_a.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV"
```

You can also use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html)